# Windows Script with Chocolatey Install and Rebooting Inbetween Steps

Tags: shell, batch-file, chocolatey

I am trying to write a short windows script that will install a few different packages using chocolatey, but it will also reboot the computer inbetween installs, then continue with the script. Below is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
call :Resume
goto %current.txt%
goto :eof

:one
::Add script to Run key
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v %~n0 /d %~dpnx0 /f
echo two >%~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section one --
    Choco install -y IOLibs
pause
shutdown -r -t 0
goto :eof

:two
echo three >%~dp0current.txt
echo -- Section two --
    Choco install -y MSCDriver
pause
shutdown -r -t 0
goto :eof

:three
::Remove script from Run key
del c:\temp\current.txt
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v %~n0 /f
echo -- Section three --
    Choco install -y HPPDriver
pause
goto :eof



:resume
if exist %~dp0current.txt (
    set /p current=<%~dp0current.txt
) else (
    set current=one
)
```

The script runs OK, however the third is where it appears to fail and not complete successfully. It looks like nothing happens. What exactly am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I like the way you are using a text tile to contain the label to goto. Hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to the RunOnce section of the Registry. How many times are you wanting it to run? :)

Looks like you are missing that reg add call to add it back into the registry in :two OR you should be using the Run section instead of RunOnce

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
if not "%~1" == "" goto %~1

:one
echo -- Section one --
    Choco install -y IOLibs
pause
call :runonce "%~f0" two
goto :eof

:two
echo -- Section two --
    Choco install -y MSCDriver
pause
call :runonce "%~f0" three
goto :eof

:three
echo -- Section three --
    Choco install -y HPPDriver
pause
goto :eof

:runonce
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v "%~n1" /d "\"%~dpnx1\" \"%~2\"" /f
shutdown -r -t 0
```

Your script sets the variable name of `current`
and you use variable name `current.txt` for
`goto %current.txt%` which would be undefined.

The script requires a repetition of using the registry
`runonce` key so it can be used in a label.

The text file is not needed as you can use script
arguments to pass the labels name for use with `goto`.
First script execution will have no arguments so the
label `:one` will be run.